# Could this set of four vectors form a basis of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have the set of four vectors,

$$\{ (1,1,1,1),(0,1,1,1),(0,0,1,1),(0,0,0,1) \}$$

Can these vectors form a basis for $\mathbb R^4$?

Comment: I don‘t understand what do you mean with „vector R“. Maybe something like „is this an $\mathbb{R}$-basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$“?

Comment: Rico, you have quite an easy task, half-solved already. Look at the _upper triangular form_  you have: $\begin{bmatrix}\color{red}{1}&1&1&1\\0&\color{red}{1}&1&1\\0&0&\color{red}{1}&1\\0&0&0&\color{red}{1}\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Start by finding out if the vectors are linearly independent. A set of vectors are linearly independent if the only linear combination of those vectors which produces $\mathbf{0}$ is the linear combination with coefficients all equal to $0$. In your case we have $4$ vectors, so we can say

$$
a_1 \cdot \mathbf{v}_1 + 
a_2 \cdot \mathbf{v}_2 + 
a_3 \cdot \mathbf{v}_3 + 
a_4 \cdot \mathbf{v}_4 = \mathbf{0} \\
a_1 \cdot \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix} +
a_2 \cdot \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix} + 
a_3 \cdot \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix} + 
a_4 \cdot \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} \\
$$

Since $\mathbf{v}_1$ is the only vector with a nonzero value in the first position, we have to make $a_1 = 0$. Since $a_1 = 0$, $\mathbf{v}_2$ is now the only remaining vector with a nonzero value in the second position, so we must make $a_2 = 0$. The same logic applies for $\mathbf{v}_3$ and $\mathbf{v}_4$ so we end up with $a_3 = 0$ and $a_4 = 0$. Since we could infer that each coefficient was equal to $0$ from the fact that the linear combination itself is $\mathbf{0}$ then the four vectors must be linearly independent.

A more elegant way to determine whether or not a set of vectors are linearly independent is to first place your column vectors together to create a matrix.

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Then use Gaussian elimination to obtain the rank of the matrix. First subtract the first row from the second, then the resulting first and second from the third, and finally, the resulting  first, second and third from the fourth.

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Since each row is nonzero, the rank of the matrix is $4$, and so your four vectors are linearly independent. Every set of four linearly independent vectors forms a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$, and so $\{(1,1,1,1), (0,1,1,1), (0,0,1,1), (0,0,0,1)\}$ must also form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are asking whether your set of vectors form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$ (since you need $4$ linearly independent vectors to span this space). Start by writing your vectors as columns in a matrix: 
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
For your vectors to span $\mathbb{R}^4$, you need to check if the vectors made of the columns of the above matrix are *linearly independent*. You can check this in a number of different ways, but an easy one (particularly for this example...) is Gaussian elimination. There are plenty of questions about Gaussian elimination on this site.